# Read items of firebase data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm begginner in web developpement.
My app is on Angular/Firebase.
I read data from RealTime Database like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value', (data) => 
           {const firstName=data.val().firstName;}
```

but it doesn't work. firstName is = "undefined"

The data i try to read is formatted like this:

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: try to console log and check what is the value present in `data`

Comment: `/users` stores the list of users. You firstly need to query a particular user ('/users/:key')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference doesn't include user id:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/M86z...').once('value', (data) => 
           {const firstName=data.val().firstName;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).  It really helps with interfacing Angular and Firebase